# Analytic crises

Tags: education, math-history

> Despite being an introduction to both the differential and integral
>   calculus, the simple and profound ideas of Newton and Leibniz will be
>   discarded in favor of the more sophisticated function-based approach
>   developed as a response to various **analytic crises** that do not really
>   apply in this setting, and that will of course not be mentioned.

It's from the book "A Mathematician's lament". What does Lockhart mean by "analytic crises" here?

Comment: His formulation has a bit of a Voldemortian touch ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I think that [HSMSE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: In that context, it means nothing... The authoir alludes to the well-known early development of *calculus*, starting with Newton and Leibniz, and the initial perplexities regarding the use of "infinitesimal quantiities (see e.g. Bishop Berkley's critique). Modern *analysis*, i.e. the foundation of calculus **no more** on geometrical intuition and motion but on *real numbers* and *functions* was developed also to answer those perplexities. It seems to me that Lockhart "analytic crises" alludes to this.